# Site gives PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR in Librewolf but not Chromium

Tags: security, browser, privacy

When I login to my bank's website, it redirects to https://auth.securebanklogin.com/ (and a bunch of other places in that domain).

On Librewolf, this eventually ends in a `PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR` page.

On Chromium, with the same extensions, I don't get `PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR`.

Because of this, I suspect that the reason is one of the additional security hardening things Librewolf includes. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _eventually_? If possible please provide a log of all (document) URLs that your browser is directed to. (Also, this site is quite insecure. It uses unchecked third-party code. Contact your bank about it.)

Comment: @DanielB Eventually = after several redirects (all on that same domain). How do I get a list of them? They happen too quick for me to follow.

Comment: As for contacting the bank, they have no clue, they just say to use some dumb adware like the MS browser.

Comment: You can use the Network view in Developer Tools to observe what the browser requests. Make sure it is set to persist entries between navigation events. At the top, you can filter for “HTML” to only get document requests.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the browser wasn't able to establish a
secure connection, because all cipher suites failed
(reached the end of the ciphers list without finding one that the
site server accepted).

So the reason for the problem isn't an additional security measure,
but a lack of security ciphers. You bank uses a security cipher
that Librewolf does not support.

The reason might be a missing cipher, or rather an old cipher that
Librewolf stopped supporting from security reasons, because of some
discovered vulnerabilities.

If you're using the latest version of Librewolf, all that's left for you
is to raise the issue in the Librewolf forums, and use Chrome(ium)
in the meantime.

Comment: That’s not what _connection reset_ means.

Comment: @DanielB: That's what this particular error code usually means. In Librewolf it might be different, but I don't use it.

Comment: The only and exact meaning of `PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR` is that the underlying TCP connection was reset or aborted. There is no statement whatsoever about the TLS negotiation.

Comment: @DanielB: I looked once into this particular error, and this was what most sources said, especially for Firefox-based browsers. I won't repeat the sources search, but just say that the website resets the connection attempt for a reason having to do with an unsuccessful connection negotiation.

Comment: “Most sources”, are, unfortunately, just plain BS. Sorry. [Mozilla source code](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amozilla%2Fgecko-dev%20PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR%20&type=code) does not lie. The correct behavior in case of a negotiation mismatch is a TLS error before the connection is gracefully closed. Firefox has different messages for that.

Comment: @DanielB: I don't get it, why do you distinguish between TLS and ciphers? One uses the other.

Comment: It also sounds strange to me that the error is called "connect_reset" if it's about running out of ciphers. However, the general idea makes sense. From past experience I know that Librewolf devs are very unreasonable and excessive about security, they disable a whole bunch commonly used SSL cyphers and they expect half the internet to magically update itself just because their sites don't work for the 0.0001% of visitors that use Librewolf (yeah right). Could you suggest a way to confirm your answer by re-enabling those cyphers?

Comment: @gomennathan: The best confirmation is that it works in other browsers, which means that Librewolf is missing support for some feature(s) that the website uses. SSL cyphers are the likely reason, although nothing is sure without tracing the exchange using Wireshark etc. From the sources I once found, it seems the this site is not the only one to do a connection reset in this case, perhaps something to do with using common web-server software or libraries.